# How to run stored procedures using IDataContext interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

Issue: I'm trying to run a stored procedure in a controller that implements the `IDataContext`.

I know how to call `databaseContext.Database.SqlQuery <string>`... but in the `IDataContext` the `Database` class isn't exposed. I'm looking for an example of the proper way to expose the `Database` class in an `IDataContext` interface, so that I can mock the `IDataContext` properly and be able to call `IDataContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>`.......

```
public class MyController : ODataController
{
    private  IDataContext _db = new DataContext();

    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("RunFile()")]
    public IHttpActionResult RunFile()
    {
        //..code omitted for brevity
        var result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<int>("exec MyStoredProc").ToList();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

I've seen a similar question to the one I'm asking but I'm looking for an example of the answer that was posted in this question. [link to Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441398/how-do-you-execute-native-sql-using-entity-framework-when-using-the-datacontext?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Basically looking for and example of how to expose the `Database` class in the `IDataContext`.

Comment: If you are in control of the code then update the interface to expose the functionality you want.

Comment: I'm looking for that example

Comment: I've added a comment to that answer asking the user to provide the example. The user seems to be active on Stack Overflow, so you might luck out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise not leaking that implementation concern. Instead expose only the desired functionality you want by updating the interface

```
public interface IDataContext {
    //...other members

    IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters);
    int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters);
}
```

and implementation.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext {
    //...other code removed for brevity

    public IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters) {
        return Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql,parameters);
    }
    public int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, params object[] parameters) {
        return Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,parameters);
    }
}
```

So now the dependent class can use only the functionality it needs

```
public class MyController : ODataController {
    private readonly IDataContext db;

    public MyController(IDataContext db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute("RunFile()")]
    public IHttpActionResult RunFile() {
        //..code omitted for brevity

        var result = db.SqlQuery<int>("exec MyStoredProc").ToList();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```